# Data import integer start with zero

Tags: clickhouse

I'm using `clickhouse` for the first time, and when I'm doing import like this:

```
cat /home/data/_XDR_IMPORT_1001_20001010_000001_.tsv | clickhouse-client --password=123 --query="INSERT INTO ts FORMAT TSV";
```

It gives me an error:

> Column 13,  name: dpc,                      type: Nullable(Int32),  parsed text: "0"
>   ERROR: garbage after Nullable(Int32): "3242"

And this is because I have a column (dpc) in type Int32 and the value of this column is 03242, so it seems the import process takes only 0 and trying to find the tap after it.

Please help anyone?

Comment: can you post your csv content?

Comment: My file is tsv not csv. here is the content for one line   (column number 14 is the dpc)                               56576471832196107 4463619586  2100   1 971135975526 971135975736 209 149 103 7 03242 6183 D618303 03429 03770 Z0377003 03429 Z618363 7 6 336346788481679 33634331833  111 32767 2 0 0 111 32767 2 0 32767 0 0 32767 0 0 32767 0  93803 938036788481679 33604807254   88886024826 22258979694 35031366230 313 7 2 80430543068   938 03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, you can use following command:

```
sed -E "s/(\t+)0([0-9]+)/\1\2/g" 1.tsv /home/data/_XDR_IMPORT_1001_20001010_000001_.tsv | clickhouse-client --password=123 --query="INSERT INTO ts FORMAT TSV";
```

and hope first column doesn't contains leading zero ;)

Answer (score 0):

change dpc field to string
and add new column

```
ALTER TABLE ts
ADD COLUMN dpc_int UInt64 MATERIALIZED toUInt64(dpc);
```

Comment: Thanks Slach, but adding new column will increase the table size, the actual size is 1 tera for everyday, do you have any other solution ?

Comment: do you mean 1Tb per day uncompressed data?
03242 is not a integer

Comment: Yes, 1Tb per day uncompressed, but 034242 is integer.